# Adding ''new'' sticker to new products

Tags: products, design

It's possible for Magento to automatically add a sticker or flash animation that says ''new'' on a product. And if it is, can it automatically remove this sticker after a period of time? 
hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Hey could you make it work?

Comment: Nope :/ sending message to the page developer as we speak, i'm still new to magento and web developing as such.

Comment: ok, keep me updated

Answer (score 0):

On products you can set the product as new from and to dates, you can then check these dates within a module block and then output html for the sticker based on if the current date is between the new from/to dates.

[image]

Then once these are set you should be able to do something like

```
    public function isProductNew($product)
    {
        $newsFromDate = $product->getNewsFromDate();
        $newsToDate   = $product->getNewsToDate();
        $currentDate = date('d/m/Y');
        if (!$newsFromDate && !$newsToDate) {
            return false;
        }
        if($currentDate > $newsFromDate && $currentDate < $newsToDate) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And then just call the above function, true = new, false = not new

Answer (score 0):

You could do it based on the '**Set Product as New from Date**' and '**Set Product as New to Date**'. 
You could a boolean too though, just create an attribute with the Yes/No input type and add it to your default attribute set. In my example the attribute is called Showcase.
Then in the product you could just choose "Yes/No" and the label we create below would come up.

In your template files (`templates/catalog/product/list.phtml` and `templates/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` if you want it on the product view page) you would add a piece of conditional code that will add the image in case the product is labeled "NEW".

***As an example:***

```
<div class="product-image">

   <?php if($_product->getShowcase()) { ?>
       <div class="newLabel"></div>
   <?php } ?>

   <?php 
       $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
       echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
   ?>

</div>
```

and then you would create specific css for the label like the following to produce the new icon in the top corner;

```
.products-grid .product-image { 
    position: relative;
    display: block; 
    width: 244px; 
    height: 156px; 
    margin: 0 0 10px;
 }

.newLabel {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 65px;
    height: 66px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    background: url(../images/yourlabel.png) no-repeat;
}
```

This is an example I did myself last week, so it uses my image sizes but you get the idea. Hope this helps.